# electrum rpc call to create a new wallet

Tags: python, json, rpc

i'am looking for a RPC call to create a new wallet with a given path. I tried something like this:

```sh
curl --data-binary '{"id":"curltext","method":"create","params": {"config_options": {"wallet_path": "/home/electrum/wallet123"}}}' http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:7000
```

But i get always this response:

```
{"result": null, "id": "curltext", "error": {"code": -32602, "message": "Invalid parameters: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'config_options'"}}
```

**Update:** After some research in my code base i found out that the function have no parameter `wallet_path`.

```py
async def create(self, passphrase=None, password=None, encrypt_file=True, segwit=False):
   d = create_new_wallet(path=self.config.get_wallet_path(),
```

The current Master Branch has it but it is not released yet.

```py
async def create(self, passphrase=None, password=None, encrypt_file=True, seed_type=None, wallet_path=None):
```

**So here is my question:**
Is it possible to manipulate self.config with an RPC command so that the create command can use a given wallet path?

Thanks

Comment: how can you manipulate `self.config` if it is not exposed through any endpoint

Comment: That is the question. If there is an endpoint.

By the method daemon it is possible with passing params:

```
curl --data-binary '{"id":"curltext","method":"daemon","params":{"config_options":{"subcommand":"load_wallet", "wallet_path":"/home/electrum/wallet123"}}}' http://user:pass@127.0.0.1:7000
```